# Modifying nodes in a flowchart with psmatrix environment

Tags: pstricks

I'm trying to draw some flowcharts with the `psmatrix` environment and I must show my input and output in a parallelogram box . 
I do not have a problem with the nodes while having the parallelogram in my flowchart but whenever I try to draw a horizontal node I encounter the problem with the below figure where a part of the node is inside of the parallelogram 
[image: image showing problem]

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}‎ 
‎\usepackage{pstricks}‎
‎\usepackage{pst-node}‎
‎\usepackage{pst-blur}‎
‎\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{1.,0.75,0.8}‎

% ‎================================‎
% ‎Source‎: ‎http://tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2009/006766.html‎

‎\makeatletter‎
‎\newdimen\psparallelogramsep‎
‎\def\psset@parallelogramsep#1{\pssetlength\psparallelogramsep{#1}}‎
‎\psset@parallelogramsep{3mm}‎
‎\def\psparallelogrambox{\pst@object{psparallelogrambox}}‎
‎\def\psparallelogrambox@i{\pst@makebox\psparallelogrambox@ii}‎
‎\def\psparallelogrambox@ii{%‎
    ‎\begingroup‎
    ‎\pst@useboxpar‎
    ‎\pst@dima=\pslinewidth‎
    ‎\advance\pst@dima by \psframesep‎
    ‎\pst@dimc=\wd\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimc by \pst@dima‎
    ‎\pst@dimb=\dp\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimb by \pst@dima‎
    ‎\pst@dimd=\ht\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimd by \pst@dima‎
    ‎\setbox\pst@hbox=\hbox{%‎
        ‎\ifpsboxsep\kern\pst@dima\fi‎
        ‎\begin@ClosedObj‎
        ‎\addto@pscode{%‎
            ‎\psk@cornersize‎
            ‎\pst@number\pst@dima neg‎
            ‎\pst@number\pst@dimb neg‎
            ‎\pst@number\pst@dimc‎
            ‎\pst@number\pst@dimd‎ .‎5‎
            ‎\pst@number\psparallelogramsep‎
            ‎\tx@Parallelogram}%‎
            ‎\def\pst@linetype{2}%‎
            ‎\showpointsfalse‎
        ‎\end@ClosedObj‎
        ‎\box\pst@hbox‎
        ‎\ifpsboxsep\kern\pst@dima\fi%‎
    }%
    ‎\ifpsboxsep\dp\pst@hbox=\pst@dimb\ht\pst@hbox=\pst@dimd\fi‎
    ‎\leavevmode\box\pst@hbox‎
    ‎\endgroup%‎
}

% ‎From the Frame and Rect PostScript macros‎
‎\pst@def{Parallelogram}<{%‎
/‎ParallelogramA‎ {
‎x1 pgs sub y1 moveto‎
‎x1 y2 lineto‎
‎x2 pgs add y2 lineto‎
‎x2 y1 lineto‎
‎x1 pgs sub y1 lineto‎
‎closepath} def‎
%
/‎pgs ED‎
‎CLW mul‎
/‎a ED‎
‎3‎ -‎1 roll‎
‎2 copy gt { exch } if‎
‎a sub‎
/‎y2 ED‎
‎a add‎
/‎y1 ED‎
‎2 copy gt { exch } if‎
‎a sub‎
/‎x2 ED‎
‎a add‎
/‎x1 ED‎
‎1 index 0 eq {pop pop ParallelogramA } { OvalFrame } ifelse}>‎
‎\makeatother‎

‎\def\pspbox[#1]#2{\makebox[#1]{\psparallelogrambox{#2}}}‎

% ‎================================‎
‎\pagestyle{empty}‎

‎\begin{document}‎
 ‎\begin{latin}‎
‎\vspace{0.5cm}‎
‎\small‎
  ‎\psset{shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90,blur=true}‎
  ‎\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.7,colsep=0.7]% defines the distance between two frames‎ 
   ‎%Begin‎
   ‎\psovalbox[fillstyle=solid‎, ‎fillcolor=yellow!30,shadow=true]{Start} \\‎
   ‎%input‎      
        ‎\psparallelogrambox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20,shadow=true]{Input r} \\‎
         ‎%Condition‎
    ‎\psdiabox[fillstyle=solid‎, ‎fillcolor=magenta!20,shadow=true]{$ r > 0 $} &‎
    ‎%output‎   
          ‎\psparallelogrambox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20,shadow=true]{Print m‎ , ‎d‎ , ‎s} \\‎ 
           ‎%computation‎
       ‎\psframebox[shadow=true]{$ d=2*r  $}  &‎ 
          ‎%End‎
            ‎\psovalbox[fillstyle=solid‎, ‎fillcolor=yellow!30,shadow=true]{End}\\‎
        ‎%computation‎
       ‎\psframebox[shadow=true]{$ m=2*\pi*r $}  \\‎
        ‎%computation‎
       ‎\psframebox[shadow=true]{$ s = \pi*r*r    $}  \\‎
        ‎%output‎   
          ‎\psparallelogrambox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20‎, ‎shadow=true]{Print Sum} \\‎ 
       % ‎Links‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{1,1}{2,1}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{3,1}{4,1}<{\textcolor{red}{Yes}}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{4,1}{5,1}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{5,1}{6,1}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{6,1}{7,1}‎
   ‎\ncline{->}{3,1}{3,2}^{\textcolor{red}{No}}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{3,2}{4,2}‎ 
     ‎\ncangles[angleA=-90,angleB=180,armA=0.5cm,armB=0.7cm]{->}{7,1}{3,1}‎
‎\end{psmatrix}‎ 
\end{document}
```

So what should I do in order to have the right nodes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the package `pstricks-add` (v. 3.57) from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks-add/

It knows the command `\psparallelogrambox` with a better code. Your example then can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{1.,0.75,0.8}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\psset{shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90,blur,shortput=nab}
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.7,colsep=0.7]
   \psovalbox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=yellow!30,shadow=true]{Start} \\
   \psparallelogrambox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20,shadow]{Input r} \\
   \psdiabox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=magenta!20,shadow=true]{$ r > 0 $} &
     \psparallelogrambox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20,shadow=true]{Print m, d, s} \\
       \psframebox[shadow=true]{$ d=2*r $}  & 
            \psovalbox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=yellow!30,shadow=true]{End}\\
       \psframebox[shadow=true]{$ m=2*\pi*r $}  \\
       \psframebox[shadow=true]{$ s=\pi*r*r $}  \\
    \psparallelogrambox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20, shadow=true]{Print Sum} 
\end{psmatrix}
\ncline{->}{1,1}{2,1}\ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1}
\ncline{->}{3,1}{4,1}_{\textcolor{red}{Yes}}
\ncline{->}{4,1}{5,1}\ncline{->}{5,1}{6,1}
\ncline{->}{6,1}{7,1}
\ncline{->}{3,1}{3,2}^{\textcolor{red}{No}}
\ncline{->}{3,2}{4,2}
\ncangles[angleA=-90,angleB=180,armA=0.5cm,armB=0.7cm]{->}{7,1}{3,1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm absolutlely unfamiliar with adding a new package ,would you tell me where can I find a good guide for that?

Comment: I mean my pstricks-add  is the 3.54 version   and I do not know how to update it to 3.57

Comment: save it into your documents directory if you do not know the place where the `pstricks-add.tex` is saved. However, have a look into the log file of your document, there you find something like `(/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/tex/generic/pstricks-add/pstricks-add.tex` which shows you the directory